# laravel show button based on the authenticated user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

how can i show the button if the user is authenticated and the id is equal to subject_id, i have already use relationship with my table and model, all i need is just to make this work.

**Controller:**

```
$subjects =Subject::with('user')->findorFail($id);
```

**View blade:**

```
@if($subjects == Auth::user())
<input style="text-align: center;border-radius:5px;"  type="submit"value="SUBMIT" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"> @else<p>View Mode</p> @endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Auth::check()` [Details doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication)

```
@if(Auth::check() && (Auth::user()->id == $subjects->id)) // check your subjectsid ... may be you named it differently
<input style="text-align: center;border-radius:5px;"  type="submit"value="SUBMIT" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
@else<p>View Mode</p>
@endif
```

Comment: Thank you sir the construction of my code is missing some id's hehe now its working thanks to you..